# On "creating" a Lipschitz continuous derivative from a strictly convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I believe the following statement to be true:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly convex twice differentiable function, call it's unique global minimum $x^*$ .

Take any differentiable function $S(x) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ 0<\ell < \frac{ d(S(x) f'(x))}{dx} < L  $$

for all $x$, where $\ell, L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $g(x):= S(x) f'(x) $ is Lipschitz continuous and the derivative of a strongly convex function with global minimum $x^*$ .

To apply this reasoning one only needs the derivative of the function $f$ and the knowledge of strict convexity.

Is this true or is something incorrect?  Is strict convexity necessary or would convexity suffice? I have the impression that if there where multiple critical points we would need to know the minimum a priori.

Comment: “Choose $S(x)$” seems ambiguous here. Does it mean that there exists an $S$ satisfying the inequality below and making $g$ satisfying the mentioned conditions, or that for any $S$ satisfying the inequality, $g$ satisfies the conditions?

Comment: Anyway, the proposition is correct for any such $S$, and $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(S(x)f'(x))>0$ already implies that $f$ is strictly convex.

Comment: @Saad That for any $S$ satisfying the inequality $g$ satisfies the condition.  Thanks you, maybe I should be clearer, will edit. If $f$ had multiple critical points would the statement still hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why $f$ has a global minimum? Take $f(x)=e^x$ on $\mathbb R$, you should add it to your hypothesis.

So suppose $f$ has a minimum point $x^*$ in $\mathbb R$, in general this result holds:

**Theorem** Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ a differentiable function and let $M>0$ such that $\lvert f'(x)\rvert \leq M$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, then $f$ is a Lipschitz continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

*Proof* For every $x, y\in\mathbb R$ with $x\leq y$ by mean value formula we get
$$
\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert =\lvert f'(\xi)(x-y)\rvert\leq M\lvert x-y\rvert
$$
for some $\xi\in [x, y]$.
$\square$

Then $g(x)=S(x)f'(x)$ is clearly a Lipcschitz function. Remember that $f$ is strictly convex if and only if $f''(t)>0$ up to countable many $t\in\mathbb R$, then set
$$
F(x)=\int^x_0S(t)f'(t)\ dt
$$
you have $F''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[S(x)f'(x)]> l>0$ so $F$ is strictly convex.

Finally because $f$ is convex we have $x^*$ is a minimum $\Leftrightarrow f'(x^*)=0$ so
$$
F'(x^*)=S(x^*)f'(x^*)=0
$$
and $x^*$ is the unique global minimum of $F$.

If $f$ is only convex we have
$$
F''(x)=S(x)f''(x)+S'(x)f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}[S(x)f'(x)]
$$
so if $f$ has multiple minimums then doesn't exists any function $S$ that satisfies your inequality, because $f''(y)=f'(y)=0$ for all these minimums. If $f$ has only one minimum then your assertion is true and $F$ is strictly convex.

Comment: " Why $f$ has a global minimum? Take $f(x)=e^x$ on $\mathbb R$   " I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Not all strictly convex functions on $\mathbb R$ have a global minimum, in fact the exponential is strictly convex and lower bounded on $\mathbb R$ but haven't any minimum.

Comment: Ok, I see thank you. Another question:  you say there does not exist a function $S$ that satisfies the inequality in the case of multiple critical points because $f''(y) = f'(y) = 0$ but by the same logic before we had that $ f''(x^*) = f'(x^*) = 0 $ no?

Comment: Take for example $f(x)=x^2$, it is strictly convex and has only one critical point at $x^*=0$, but $f''(x^*)=2>0$.

Comment: In general if a $C^1$ convex function $f$ has multiple critical points then all these points are (global) minimum points for $f$ and the set $I$ of critical points for $f$ is an interval in $\mathbb R$. Then $f$ is constant on $I$.

Comment: So could I relax the assumptions by requiring that the additional minimum $y$ was such that $f''(y)>0$ ?

Comment: I don't understand how you would relax your assumption. If you require only that $f''(x^*)>0$ then $F=\int Sf$ could not be convex nor Lipschitz and $x^*$ may not be the minimum for $F$.

Comment: No I meant to say, that we assume there are multiple minima $y_1, y_2$ but we impose that $ f''(y_1) > 0, f''(y_2) > 0 $, to allow for the possibility of multiple minima. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: You need at least that $M\geq \frac d{dx}[S(x)f'(x)]\geq 0$ on $\mathbb R$ and it's strictly positive when $x=x^*$.